# Receiving JSON between local React App and local Springboot service issues

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, google-chrome

I am running a local Springboot server, that when I access it locally in the browser, gives me a valid JSON object properly formatted (I verified this via JSON formatter).

I am also locally running a React application using node. I am attempting to use fetch() to get back that JSON object and running into issues. Finally got around CORs header issues, but not cannot figure out why the JSON object isn't coming back. Here's my code

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

var myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: headers,
               mode: 'no-cors',
               cache: 'default',
};    

fetch(`http://localhost:3010/getJSON`, myInit)
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
  },function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
```

So when I run this in Chrome with the debugger, the responses to the 3 log statements are:

1st logger

```
undefined
```

2nd logger

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false,         
…}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
false
redirected
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
"opaque"
url
:
""
__proto__
:
Response
```

3rd logger

```
{}
```

I have tried many different JSON parsing, stringify, etc, to no avail.

The next confusing part, is if within the Chrome debugger I go to the "Network" tab, click on the /getJSON, it shows me the entire JSON object just fine in both the "Preview" and "Response" tabs. So clearly Chrome is connecting to it correctly. Here's Chrome's "Headers" tab within "Network":

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3010/getJSON
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:[::1]:3010
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 12 Oct 2017 16:05:05 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3010
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

I have tried to mimic this header in my request, but not sure how it differs? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am currently banging my head against the way with this!

Comment: try hitting your api with RestClient or Postman and verify wether the data is coming properly

Comment: You need to not specify `mode: 'no-cors'`. The reason the JSON object isn’t coming back is because you specified `mode: 'no-cors'`. What the tells the browser is, *“Don’t under any circumstances allow my frontend JavaScript code to access the response.”* If the reason you’ve specified `mode: 'no-cors'` is that you otherwise get a CORS error, then the right way to fix that it  is to configure the server you’re making the request to so that it sends back the right CORS headers in its response.

Comment: The reason you can see the response the devtools Network tab is that the browser gets the response just fine. But just because the browser gets the response doesn’t mean it will expose that response to your frontend JavaScript code. The browser will only expose the response to your code if the response includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an opaque response, which tells me that maybe you haven't completely resolved the cors headers situation. If you're fetching from the client, I would suggest proxying that through your nodejs so that instead of calling your springboot service, you call node, thus getting rid of the cors issues.

**EDIT**

You could create something like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import request from 'request';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/proxyname', (req, res) => {
  // Removing IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format, if present
  const requestUrl = [your service's endpoint];

  request(requestUrl, (err, apiResponse, body) => {
    res.status(apiResponse.statusCode);
    try {
      res.json(JSON.parse(body));
    } catch (e) {
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

and then on your nodejs server file, add it, like this:

```
import proxy from '[path to proxy file above]';
app.use('/path-to-endpoint', proxy);
```

and then call that from the client instead of your SpringBoot service.

Comment: So I've tried looking into adding a proxy through the package.json, and also tried to use an http-agent within my fetch() call, but haven't had luck with either thus far. Any suggestions?

Comment: On your original question, you mention "I am also locally running a React application using node". That's where I got the idea for the proxy. You'd have to create an endpoint with express or whatever http library you're using. From that endpoint's body, you would call your SpringBoot service and return the response.

Comment: Just added an example of what I mean on to my answer, assuming you're running this on nodejs